# play framework templates onchange possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, playframework, onchange

I have got different @inputText templates given. They look like that:

```
@inputText( 
addLiftForm("xyz"),
'_label -> null,
'_showConstraints -> false,
)
```

Is it possible to use an onchange function on that textfield?

Answer (score 0):

Why just not test? Yes you can add other attributes to the form helper fields, like

```
@inputText( 
  addLiftForm("xyz"),
  '_label -> null,
  '_showConstraints -> false,
  'onchange -> "alert('changed');",
  Symbol("data-foo") -> "bar"
)
```

- Last in case when you want to add attribute with special characters
  (like `data-foo="bar"`)